# DBpedia query returns some musicals more than once despite filters

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I'm trying to use a SPARQL query against DBpedia to retrieve a list of musicals and some associated properties. However, despite using the appropriate filters (as far as I can tell), the results include many of the musicals more than once. Here is my query:

```
    PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
    PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
    PREFIX dbpprop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
    SELECT ?label ?abstract ?book ?music ?lyrics
    WHERE { 
        ?play <http://purl.org/dc/terms/subject> <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Broadway_musicals> ;
            rdfs:label ?label ;
            dbo:abstract ?abstract ;
            dbpprop:book ?book ;
            dbpprop:lyrics ?lyrics ;
            dbpprop:music ?music .
        FILTER (LANG(?label) = 'en')    
        FILTER (LANG(?abstract) = 'en')
        FILTER (LANG(?book) = 'en')
        FILTER (LANG(?lyrics) = 'en')
        FILTER (LANG(?music) = 'en')
    }
```

The resulting list has many duplicate entries. Pasting the query here:
[DBpedia SPARQL Explorer](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/), you'll see that starting with 'Mama Mia!' there are a lot of duplicates in the list.

Any idea what I'm missing to get unique results with no duplicates? Thanks!

[Edited by glenn mcdonald to clarify that it's musicals which are "duplicated" here, not triples.]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SPARQL returns variable-bindings. Your "duplicates" are cartesian products of multiples in your projected properties. Mamma Mia has multiple music writers and multiple lyricists, so you get every possible combination of them that could produce a row in your table.

What a pain, huh? The "solution" is to use CONSTRUCT instead of SELECT, and deal with getting back a graph instead of a table. Maybe like this:

http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=PREFIX+rdfs%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0D%0A++++PREFIX+dbo%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0A++++PREFIX+dbpprop%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fproperty%2F%3E%0D%0A++++CONSTRUCT+%7B%0D%0A++++++++%3Fplay+rdfs%3Alabel+%3Flabel+%3B%0D%0A++++++++++++dbo%3Aabstract+%3Fabstract+%3B%0D%0A++++++++++++dbpprop%3Abook+%3Fbook+%3B%0D%0A++++++++++++dbpprop%3Alyrics+%3Flyrics+%3B%0D%0A++++++++++++dbpprop%3Amusic+%3Fmusic+.%0D%0A++++%7D%0D%0A++++WHERE+%7B+%0D%0A++++++++%3Fplay+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fdc%2Fterms%2Fsubject%3E+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2FCategory%3ABroadway_musicals%3E+%3B%0D%0A++++++++++++rdfs%3Alabel+%3Flabel+%3B%0D%0A++++++++++++dbo%3Aabstract+%3Fabstract+%3B%0D%0A++++++++++++dbpprop%3Abook+%3Fbook+%3B%0D%0A++++++++++++dbpprop%3Alyrics+%3Flyrics+%3B%0D%0A++++++++++++dbpprop%3Amusic+%3Fmusic+.%0D%0A++++++++FILTER+%28LANG%28%3Flabel%29+%3D+%27en%27%29++++%0D%0A++++++++FILTER+%28LANG%28%3Fabstract%29+%3D+%27en%27%29%0D%0A++++++++FILTER+%28LANG%28%3Fbook%29+%3D+%27en%27%29%0D%0A++++++++FILTER+%28LANG%28%3Flyrics%29+%3D+%27en%27%29%0D%0A++++++++FILTER+%28LANG%28%3Fmusic%29+%3D+%27en%27%29%0D%0A++++%7D

Comment: This really only works because graphs don't have duplicate triples, and it leaves you with a problem to deal with parsing the RDF syntax, so I think Rob's answer is more useful.

Comment: RobV didn't look at the data, but wrote a quick speculative answer about what might work, in case it applied. This is a fine thing to do, but in this case I actually looked at the data and knew that it wasn't a duplicate problem. So Rob's answer can't possibly be "more useful" than mine, since it isn't useful in this case at all.

Comment: that makes perfect sense, thanks! I am new to SPARQL, but I see why I was getting multiple results. I'll research the CONSTRUCT statement and how to handle graph results properly.

Comment: @Glenn No I didn't look at the data but I wrote an answer which is a general purpose answer that addresses the underlying problem rather than just this specific query.  It is far better that Ganesh understand why he gets duplicate results (which fwiw your answer does explain nicely) and ways to remove them rather than just how to fix this one query.  And I am inclined to agree with Steve that your `CONSTRUCT` workaround just hides the problem rather than solving it

Comment: @RobV, I don't have any issue with your answer. You said "if this is the problem, then this is the solution", which is fine. You're not obligated to look at his data in detail. But given that I did, and that in fact his problem is not duplicate bindings but cartesian products, claiming that CONSTRUCT is a "workaround" that "hides the problem" makes no sense. SPARQL has no better solution than that. And DISTINCT is not "solving" the problem in this case, it's irrelevant. So the downvote seems inappropriate, but whatever.

Comment: @Glenn For the record I actually upvoted your answer - I assume it was Steve who downvoted it.  CONSTRUCT is hiding the problem since like Steve points out you seem to be exploiting the fact that duplicate Triples generated are silently discarded which may solve this specific problem but is not a general panacea

Comment: I still don't understand how CONSTRUCT is "hiding" the problem of cartesian products, which is what Ganesh actually has (duplicate *musicals*, not duplicate triples). Oh, I just realized I'm allowed to edit the question to clarify it. That will help.

Comment: Just a followup to everyone on this thread: As you pointed out, each musical can have more than one composer or lyricist, which results in a row in the table for each cartesian product of musical and composer or lyricist, rsulting in duplicate musicals. I switched to using the CONSTRUCT statement, and got a RDF graph of subject, predicate and object triples. I went through a quick primer of Python's rdflib and have successfully parsed the graph using rdflib. Thanks for your insight, this thread really introduced me to concepts of semantics and the basic concepts of RDF.

Answer (score 3):

Are the duplicates exact duplicates?  i.e. every value for every variable of each duplicate result is identical

If so then add the `DISTINCT` keyword after `SELECT` to force the SPARQL engine to discard duplicates solutions.

If not then Glenn is entirely correct that because there are multiple values given for the various properties so you will get multiple results.  There are complex workarounds you can do with subqueries, `GROUP BY` etc. but they would tend to lead to less efficient queries.  Sometimes you just have to deal with the duplicates on the client side.